# Receive data from php script as soon as they are flushed

Tags: php, curl

Suppose I have a php file like this running on a remote server:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    ob_start();

    echo "Step $i of 9<br>";

    sleep(1.0);

    ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
}
```

This prints a line like 'Step x of 9' every second.
Now suppose I want to call this file from another server. I'm trying using curl and the code looks like this:

```
function PostData($data)
{
    global $bridgeURL;

    $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $bridgeURL);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);

        $result = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);

    return $result;     
}
```

It works well, but receives the whole output all at once. 
Is there a way to receive data each time the remote script flushes? It does not need to be curl. Any method is welcome. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Include your function file (let's say functions.php) in your curl file (let's say curl.php). Then just call your function from inside your loop.

```
include 'functions.php;`
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    ob_start();

    $post_data = PostData($data); //assume $data is define somewhere else

    echo "Step $i of 9<br>";

    sleep(1.0);

    ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Don't think I can do that. I tried to simplify the question to be more clear. The target script is doing a long operation that requires about 50 seconds. I need to get back on the other script periodical updates of the current status

Comment: I think the main thing is that I fail to see how the two scripts you show are related to each other. Perhaps I mistunderstood.

Comment: Yes, it was the case, but your misunderstanding was due to my fault trying to explain. I finally solved the problem creating a callback and passing it to curl as CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION. Thank you anyway for the help. Much appreciated